# Commerce Point of Sale (POS)

Tags: 7, commerce

I do not know how to use the last module "project/commerce_pos" version 2 dev. I can not even get a view point of sale. Can you tell me how to access the point of sale? there is no documentation.
[image]
I know how to access the settings, but I can not access the page above to use the pos

[image]

I do not see how to add products

Comment: Hi. As mentioned below, you access the POS itself via: admin/commerce/pos

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the latest 7.x-2.x-dev version to get latest fixes. See this issue relating to products not showing: https://www.drupal.org/node/2708543

Comment: Solved the issue? If so please accept answer. As mentioned below, adding products is done as part of normal commerce process e.g. admin/commerce/products/add

Answer (score 1):

You will find some documentation in the README.txt that comes with the module.

To use the module, you first need to get drupal commerce up and running. Then your products will be available for sale via the POS, once installed.

Also look at the [commerce pos issues queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_pos?categories=All) as v2 still has some issues being resolved.

I have used 7.x-1.x-dev extensively, and you can access the POS via: admin/commerce/pos

The configuration is via: admin/commerce/pos/config

If you have any specific question, please amend your original question.

Edit:

1. Make sure you are using the latest 7.x-2.x-dev version to get latest fixes.
2. Also see this issue relating to products not showing: [By default, no products are available in the POS](http://drupal.org/node/2708543)
3. POS is available via: admin/commerce/pos

Comment: How can i enable/add "Create new customer" button in pos transaction form. I am using commerce_pos 7.x-2.x-dev version.

Comment: You will probably have to use one of the hooks to modify the form. Post your question on commerce_pos queue on drupal.org